# Creating a simple FOR INSERT trigger on a table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I need help creating a quick FOR INSERT trigger for a table called dbo.Employees using the popular Northwind sample database. The trigger should default the 'Region' column in dbo.Employees to 'WA' if no region was inserted.

And if the region inserted was 'WA', then the 'Country' column should default to 'USA'. Any help would be much appreciated.

The employees table if it helps:

[image: 1]

Comment: A trigger is the wrong way to do this.  A `default` constraint is the right way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm doing this purely as an exercise to learn which is why I want to use the FOR INSERT trigger

Comment: . . There are many things that triggers can do and are needed for.  It is sad when exercises teach using them in inappropriate circumstances.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the help though, I see what you mean, I'll try and learn some more on triggers and their uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Gordon Linoff said, this should be a constraint, but if you really needs to get this done using triggers, this will work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.EmployeesTrigger ON dbo.Employees
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE E
    SET E.Country = CASE I.Country
            WHEN 'WA' THEN 'USA'
            ELSE ISNULL(I.Country, 'WA')
        END
    FROM dbo.Employees AS E
    INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I
        ON I.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID;
END
```

It will update record once something has been inserted.

- If WA was inserted as a country, it will update it to USA
- If NULL or nothing was inserted, it will default to WA
- On any other case, it will insert whatever was inserted, let's say Canada